# Sublime Text3 creates Scripts inside Scripts folder inside virtualenv

Tags: python, python-2.7, sublimetext3, virtualenv

I'm trying to run Python scripts inside virtualenv from Sublime Text 3. When I activate the virtualenv in ST3 and choose the `.py`, ST3 creates a `Scripts` folder inside the preexisting `Scripts` folder (for a new `.py'). What is causing this problem and how I do stop this from happening?

Following are the detailed steps I follow:

1. Create `virtualenx Somevenv' from CMD
2. Navigate to 'Someenv\Scripts`
3. activate
4. `pip install somePackage`
5. Select `Virtualenv:New` (`Virtualenv: Activate` does nothing)
6. Paste `\path\to\Someenv\Scripts` under `Virtualenv Path`
7. Select `c:\Python27`
8. ST3 does it's thing and produces this message:

   `New python executable in C:\Users\Gandalf\Documents\Python_Virtual_Env\Legolas\Scripts\Scripts\python.exe
   Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...done.`

As you see, ST3 creates a `Scripts` inside the previous `Scripts` folder. As a result, the packages installed in step 4 are not used. I want to stop the creation of this second `Scripts` folder.

Answer (score 0):

Solved. In ST3, use `Virtualenv: Add Directory` instead of `Virtualenv: New`. The latter creates a new virtualenv (hence the new Scripts folder).